# How do I use identation in try block properly?

Tags: python

This piece of code is getting me an error of invalid syntax on first `return render` line. I guess I have messed up my identation, but i do not know how exactly I did.

```
def searchView(request):
if request.method == 'GET':
    query = request.GET.get('search')
    try:
        result = Vacancy.objects.filter(name__icontains = query)
    return render(request, "search.html", {'vacancies': result })
else:
    return render(request, "search.html", {})
```

Comment: A `try` requires an `except` or a `finally`.

Answer (score 1):

your `try`

should have `except`

do this

```
try:
   #something
except:
   pass
```

i.e

```
def searchView(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        query = request.GET.get('search')
        try:
            result = Vacancy.objects.filter(name__icontains = query)
        except:
            pass
        return render(request, "search.html", {'vacancies': result })
    else:
        return render(request, "search.html", {})
```